# Отображение фотографий на сайте по определенному хэштэгу

Tags: instagram

Друзья, добрый день!
Помогите, пожалуйста, вот с такм вопросом. Мы со студентами делаем мультимедийную страницу на сайте университета. Перед нами стоит задача встроить instagram окно, в котором будут отображаться фотографии, добавленные студентами по определенному хэштэгу. В данному случае тематика у нас новогодняя - как студент НГ отмечают.). Может ли быть такая задача реализована? В таком ли виде? Подскажите, как мы можем настроить такую штуку на сайте. 
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/242643/ Вот прочитайте, там как раз по теме.

Comment: @Shlapper, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.